# Using JPA to access a view without a unique id returns null

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am using JPA and have a view I would like to access. I am using a mapped entity with an embedded Id in many of my other classes to access tables with similar requirements. However here whenever there are nulls in the view that comprise the id, the whole object is returned as null. There are the right number of entities returned when i query, but they are null.

Here are the classes:

```
{
@Entity
@Table(name = "VW_PRODUCT")
public class VwProduct implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    private VwProductId id;

    public VwProduct() {
    }
}

{
@Embeddable
public class VwProductId implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Column(name = "PROD_NAME", nullable=true)
    private String prodName;
    @Column(name = "PROD_CTGRY", nullable=true)
    private String prodCtgry;
    @Column(name = "PROD_SBCTGRY", nullable=true)
    private String prodSbctgry;
}
```

I omitted things like getters and setters and hashcode but i think my question is clear; how do I access this view, when some of its values are null?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a primary key column with null, and search on that column will always return no objects.

There are three possible solutions that I am aware of, in order of complexity/wonkiness. (For people not working on a read-only view, do not do any of the following.  You will blow your foot off with an incredibly large shotgun.)

The easiest answer is to change your definition of the view and add something like a rowid or generated serial and then make that the primary key.

The second answer, and this is both implementation specific and hibernate specific, is to have a primary key of `@ID @ROWID String id;`

The last answer, is more complex, is by mapping all three of your fields to a "NullableString" `UserType`, and have a `nullSafeGet` that maps `null` to something non-null, like '' or something.  You'll get duplicates, but since this is a read-only view, you don't really care.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, I actually did the first option when I realized I had faced this issue before and looked up how I had fixed it. The other two options sound like interesting ideas as well, that maybe ill try next time. Thanks again!